# Sharing Add-in between Office Apps

Tags: c#, com, ms-office, add-in

I have written an Office shared Add-in with C# and .NET 2.0. It uses the same COM Shim for all office apps. Currently, every instance creates its own instance of my class -- they have no knowledge of the fact that the add-in is running on another application.

Is it possible to make it so that, say, when the Word add-in launches it can detect that the Excel add-in is already running? Can they communicate between each other?

Let's say my dll is called Addin.dll. When, for example, Word opens, it runs the code in Addin.dll that implements the IExtensibility interface, and creates a class, let's call it WordAddin. When Excel opens, it also runs the code in Addin.dll, and it creates an instance of ExcelAddin. Now, suppose that Word is running and WordAddin exists. When Excel is opened, Addin.dll is loaded into a different AppDomain. It has no knowledge that WordAddin exists. I want ExcelAddin to have know WordAddin exists, and be able to communicate with it, perhaps through a parent class that creates both.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using named pipes to communicate between processes

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using a Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ): [Use Microsoft Message Queuing in C# for inter-process communication](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6170794.html)

This code project article shows how to detect a running instance and how to copy command line parameters between them:

[Single-Instance C# Application - for .NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSSIApp.aspx)

Not quite what you are asking but might be of interest: [Detecting a running instance of a program and passing it information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632522/detecting-a-running-instance-of-a-program-and-passing-it-information/632578)

Comment: Thanks!

Let's say my dll is called Addin.dll. When, for example, Word opens, it runs the code in Addin.dll that implements the IExtensibility interface, and creates a class, let's call it WordAddin. When Excel opens, it also runs the code in Addin.dll, and it creates an instance of ExcelAddin.

Now, suppose that Word is running and WordAddin exists. When Excel is opened, Addin.dll is loaded into a different AppDomain. It has no knowledge that WordAddin exists. I want ExcelAddin to have know WordAddin exists, and be able to communicate with it, perhaps through a parent class that creates both.

Answer (score 0):

I have in fact done exactly what you're asking about. I went for old fashioned windows messages. Nothing fancy - so it will just work! :-)

Let your addin create a "window" using the NativeWindow class and give it a predetermned, unique name. Then search for another instance of such a window using [GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633515(VS.85).aspx) and GetWindowText when your addin launches. Communicate using SendMessage or PostMessage. Easy as that.